# Windows Phone 10 Universal, how to resize and move a rectangle?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am pretty new to C# and XAML, and I am trying to create an application that allows the user to move a rectangle, resize the rectangle using pinch, and change the color when touched. I have successfully created the application for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, but I am having a lot of trouble creating it for Windows Phone 10 Universal. There is very limited literature out there in regards to handling manipulation events in Windows Phone 10.

Can someone please direct me to the appropriate information for doing this, or if you could show me where I went wrong in my code?

I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you,

Page

Here is my MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="Gesture_App_UWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Gesture_App_UWP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               Height="50" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Gesture Application" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Width="360" FontSize="36" TextAlignment="Center" 
               FontFamily="Bauhaus 93" Margin="0,25,0,0" >
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF23AFE2" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>

    <Button x:Name="button_Info" Content="Info" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="34" Margin="35,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" 
            Click="button_Info_Click" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="#FFFA9F11" 
            BorderBrush="#FF09B4F3">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF3A3939" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="button_Instructions" Content="Instructions" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="34" Margin="210,91,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" BorderThickness="2" 
            Foreground="#FFFA9F11" BorderBrush="#FF09B4F3" Click="button_Instructions_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF3A3939" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>

    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="5" Margin="10,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="340"/>

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="475" Margin="0,165,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360"/>

    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="470" Margin="0,170,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="360" >

        <Rectangle Name="touchRectangle" Fill="Green" Width="200" Height="40" Canvas.Left="80" 
                   Stroke="Blue" Canvas.Top="190" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   ManipulationMode="All"/>
    </Canvas>


</Grid>
</Page>
```

Here is my MainPage.xaml.cs, I have updated it to reflect the changes mentioned below and still the rectangle does not move or resize.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Input;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Gesture_App_UWP
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    // Global translation transform used for changing the position of 
    // the Rectangle based on input data from the touch contact.
    private TranslateTransform dragTranslation;
    private CompositeTransform deltaTransform;
    private TransformGroup rectangleTransforms;

    //Various Brushes for changing rectangle's color
    private Brush stationaryBrush;
    private SolidColorBrush greenBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    private SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    private SolidColorBrush orangeBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Pointer event listeners.
        touchRectangle.PointerPressed += touchRectangle_PointerPressed;
        touchRectangle.PointerReleased += touchRectangle_PointerReleased;

        // Listener for Manipulation events
        touchRectangle.ManipulationStarted += new ManipulationStartedEventHandler(touchRectangle_ManipulationStarted);
        touchRectangle.ManipulationDelta += new ManipulationDeltaEventHandler(touchRectangle_ManipulationDelta);
        touchRectangle.ManipulationInertiaStarting += new ManipulationInertiaStartingEventHandler(touchRectangle_ManipulationInertiaStarting);
        touchRectangle.ManipulationCompleted += new ManipulationCompletedEventHandler(touchRectangle_ManipulationCompleted);

        //Initiate new instance of various Transforms
        dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
        deltaTransform = new CompositeTransform();
        rectangleTransforms = new TransformGroup();

        // Combine moving & resizing tranforms into one TransformGroup.
        // Rectangle's RenderTransform can only contain a single transform or TransformGroup.
        rectangleTransforms.Children.Add(dragTranslation);
        rectangleTransforms.Children.Add(deltaTransform);

        //Assign manipulation data to rectangle
        touchRectangle.RenderTransform = rectangleTransforms;
    }
    private async void button_Info_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog_Info = new MessageDialog("Page Lynn Potter");
        await dialog_Info.ShowAsync();
    }
    private async void button_Instructions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dialog_Instructions = new MessageDialog("PINCH - Zoom In & Out, LONG TOUCH - Toggle Color, FLICK - Move Rectangle");
        await dialog_Instructions.ShowAsync();
    }
    //Handler for pointer released event.
    private void touchRectangle_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Change rectangle's color
        touchRectangle.Fill = greenBrush;
    }
    // Handler for pointer pressed event.
    private void touchRectangle_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Change rectangle's color
        touchRectangle.Fill = orangeBrush;
    }
    void touchRectangle_ManipulationInertiaStarting(object sender, ManipulationInertiaStartingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Change rectangle's color
        touchRectangle.Fill = redBrush;
    }
    void touchRectangle_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Save rectangle's original color before changing color.
        stationaryBrush = touchRectangle.Fill;

        //Change rectangle's color
        touchRectangle.Fill = orangeBrush;
    }

    // Handler for ManipulationDelta event.
    // ManipulationDelta data loaded into translation transform & applied to Rectangle
    void touchRectangle_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY | ManipulationModes.Scale;

        // Move rectangle.
        dragTranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        dragTranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;


        // Resize rectangle.
        if (deltaTransform.ScaleX > 0 && deltaTransform.ScaleY > 0)
        {
            //Scale Rectangle
            deltaTransform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
            deltaTransform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
        }
    }
    //When manipulation ends, event handler restores original color to Rectangle
    void touchRectangle_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Restore rectangle's original color.
        touchRectangle.Fill = stationaryBrush;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You're assigning `touchRectangle.RenderTransform` twice, first with a TranslateTransform, then with an empty CompositeTransform, which replaces the previously assigned transform.

Comment: Thank you! I will fix that and recompile.

Comment: I tried that, I commented out the extra touchRectangle.RenderTransform and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified working exmple of a Rectangle that can be moved and scaled by touch input.

Note that a `ScaleTransform` and a `TranslateTransform` are added to a `TransformGroup` in XAML. Instead of setting `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`, the TranslateTransform is initialized with their values.

The `RenderTransformOrigin` property is set such that the scaling takes place at the center of the Rectangle.

It may also be sufficient to set `ManipulationMode="Scale,TranslateX,TranslateY"` instead of `All`.

```
<Rectangle ManipulationDelta="Rectangle_ManipulationDelta"
           ManipulationMode="All" Fill="Red"
           Width="200" Height="40" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"
           RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" X="80" Y="190"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

The only code behind is the ManipulationDelta handler:

```
private void Rectangle_ManipulationDelta(
    object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    scaleTransform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
    translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me! I finally got it working the way I want. I will try doing it with the RenderTransform & TransformGroup in my xaml as well, and see how that one works. The thing that got my code working was setting my ManipulationModes in the constructor, I must have set them improperly inside ManipulationDelta event handler.

Answer (score 0):

As Clemens said, you're assigning `touchRectangle.RenderTransform` twice. When you second time set the `touchRectangle.RenderTransform`, it will replace the first time that you set. So the `TranslateTransform` will not work.

We should be able to use a [`TransformGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.TransformGroup) to group two or more `Transform` objects into a single composite Transform.

For example:

```
private TranslateTransform dragTranslation;
private CompositeTransform deltaTransform;
private TransformGroup myTransformGroup;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    touchRectangle.PointerReleased += touchRectangle_PointerReleased;
    touchRectangle.ManipulationDelta += touchRectangle_ManipulationDelta;
    dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
    deltaTransform = new CompositeTransform();
    myTransformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    myTransformGroup.Children.Add(dragTranslation);
    myTransformGroup.Children.Add(deltaTransform);
    touchRectangle.RenderTransform = myTransformGroup;
}
```

Comment: I did everything that was mentioned and still to no avail does the rectangle move or resize. I will add my updated code to the post, I may have missed something that just needs another set of eyes to find.

Comment: @Potter I have tested that the Rectangle can be moved and resized.

Comment: Just a note, the TransformGroup doesn't need to be a class member, the other two transforms could be readonly members.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input, I am greatly appreciative that you took the time to help me out. I finally got it working!